# pyftpdlib slow .read on file blocks entire mainloop

Tags: python, asynchronous, ftp, asyncore, eventlet

Helllo,

I am using a custom `AbstractFS` on `pyftpdlib` that maps files on a HTTP server to FTP.
This files are returned by my implementation of `open` (of `AbstractFS`) which returns a `httplib.HTTPResponse` wrapped by the following class:

```
class HTTPConnWrapper:
    def __init__(self, obj, filename):
        # make it more file obj like
        self.obj = obj
        self.closed = True
        self.name = filename.split(os.sep)[-1]

    def seek(self, arg):
        pass

    def read(self, bytes):
        #print 'read', bytes
        read = self.obj.read(100) #we DONT read var byes, but 100 bytes
        #print 'ok'
        return read
```

The problem is that if a client is downloading files the entire server becommes sluggish.
What can I do?
Any ideas?

PS:
And why just monkey patching everything with `evenetlet` does'nt magically makes everything work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I posted a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/pyftpdlib/issues/detail?id=197&colspec=ID%20Summary%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Opened) on pyftpdlib:

> I wouldn't even know what to recommend exactly as it's a problem which is hard to resolve and there's no easy or standard way to deal with it.

But I got a crazy solution to solve this problem without using pyftpdlib.

1. rewrite everything using wsgidav (which uses the cherrypy
   wsgiserver, so its threaded)
2. mount that WebDAV filesystem as native filesystem (`net use` on
   windows, `mount.davfs` on linux)
3. serve this mounted filesystem with any ftp server that can handle
   blocking file systems

Answer (score 2):

pyftpdlib uses Python's `asyncore` module which polls and interacts with `dispatcher`s. Each time you map an FTP request to a request to the HTTP server you're blocking the `asyncore` loop that pydftpdlib is using. You should implement your HTTP requests as dispatchers that fit the asyncore model, or generate threads to handle the request asynchronously and post the result back to the FTP request handler when the data has arrived. This is somewhat difficult as there's no provided mechanism to interrupt asyncore's polling loop from external threads.

As for eventlet, I don't know that it would play nicely with asyncore, which is already utilizing a nonblocking IO mechanism.

Comment: the problem is that i can not control when .read is called on the file, what can I do if read is called when there is no data available?

Comment: `eventlet.green.asyncore` exists so it seems like eventlet supports asyncore